# Integrate Google Calendar API into WordPress Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, calendar, google-calendar-api

I've a calendar plugin working with my WordPress and I want to integrate Google Calendar API to Create, Read, Update, Delete Google Calendar Events. This is the process I followed.

I've created a function inside different Calendar plugin Class, that I got from the Google Calendar API documentation (https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php):

```
function getClient() {
        try{
            $client = new Google_Client();
            $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API');
            $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
            $client->setAuthConfig(AEC_PATH .'credentials.json');
            $client->setAccessType('offline');
            $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

            // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
            // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
            // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
            // time.
            $tokenPath = 'token.json';
            if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
                $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
                $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
            } else {
                print 'Access Token not generated!!';
            }

            // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
            if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
                // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
                if ($client->getRefreshToken()) {
                    $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
                } else {
                    // Request authorization from the user.
                    $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
                    printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
                    print 'Enter verification code: ';
                    $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

                    // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
                    $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
                    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

                    // Check to see if there was an error.
                    if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken)) {
                        throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
                    }
                }
                // Save the token to a file.
                if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath))) {
                    mkdir(dirname($tokenPath), 0700, true);
                }
                file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
            }

            return $client;
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Now I've added an action hook in constructor to initialize this function.

```
add_action('init', array($this, 'getClient'));
```

Now I'm calling this function getClient() in another function to call at particular time interval.

```
try{
            // Get the API client and construct the service object.
            $client = $this->getClient();
            $service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
            $calendarId = '<Google_Calendar_ID>';

            $event = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event(array(
                'summary' => $input->title,
                'location' => $input->address.''.$input->city.''.$input->state.''.$input->country.''.$input->zip,
                'description' => $input->description,
                'start' => array(
                    'dateTime' => '2019-09-22T09:00:00-07:00'
                ),
                'end' => array(
                    'dateTime' => '2019-09-22T17:00:00-07:00'
                ),
                'reminders' => array(
                    'useDefault' => FALSE,
                    'overrides' => array(
                    array('method' => 'email', 'minutes' => 24 * 60),
                    array('method' => 'popup', 'minutes' => 10),
                    ),
                ),
            ));

            $event = $service->events->insert($calendarId, $event);
            echo "--Google Event Created-->";
            print_r($event);
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            print_r($e->getMessage());
        }
```

Instead of new event created to my Google Calendar I'm getting an authorization error.

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
    "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes."
 }
```

Could you please help me in understanding why I'm getting this error and how can I resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

delete your token.pickle file, then run your script

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.readonly']
```

change to

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar']
```

Comment: I tried deleting and regenerating. My Token isn't readonly.

"scope": "https:\/\/www.googleapis.com\/auth\/calendar"

Comment: you need to delete that token.pickle file

Comment: The function is calling `$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);` and instead of `$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR_READONLY);` so it's not in **Read-only mode**. I've checked that.

Comment: have you deleted the token.pickle file

Comment: Yes, deleted and regenerated with this change

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200218/discussion-between-siddharth-jain-and-sayed-mohd-ali).

Answer (score 0):

This error is due a stale credentials, not an error in your code. To solve the situation you will have to delete the file named `token.json` and execute the code. You will be prompted to accept your app again with new scopes. If it is still failing, I recommend deleting both `token.json` and `credentials.json`; the latter for being corrupted.

If that didn't work, please check that your scope is written exactly the same as it appears on [Authorizing requests with OAuth 2.0](https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth#OAuth2Authorizing) and repeat the procedure.

Comment: Process I'm following:
1. Deleted token.json and re-download credentials.json from the Google Console.
2. To hit quickstart.php (created a separate file in the same folder) from cmd and generate the token.json
3. Then login to my wordpress admin and creating an new calendar entry that calls the Google Calendar APIs to insert data.
4. Still ending up in the same error.

Comment: Hi there @SiddharthJain, just to make sure I want to ask you something: are you following a link from the terminal to Google which ask for permissions? If you already did that, the error may fall on Wordpress side.

Comment: Yes, once I hit `php quickstart.php` from the terminal it generates a link and after giving permissions it shared a code that we have to enter back to terminal and then it generates the token.json

Comment: @SiddharthJain, that is the correct approach to generate a `token.json`. This indicates that the problem lies on the Wordpress set up.